# Extract multiple key:value pairs from one dict to a new dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dict what some data, and I would like to extract certain key:value pairs into a new list of dicts.  I know one way that I could do this would be to use `del i['unwantedKey']`, however, I would rather not delete any data but instead create a new dict with the needed data.

The column order might change, so I need something to extract the two key:value pairs from the larger dict into a new dict.

**Current Data Format**

```
[{'Speciality': 'Math', 'Name': 'Matt', 'Location': 'Miami'},
 {'Speciality': 'Science', 'Name': 'Ben', 'Location': 'Las Vegas'}, 
 {'Speciality': 'Language Arts', 'Name': 'Sarah', 'Location': 'Washington DC'},
 {'Speciality': 'Spanish', 'Name': 'Tom', 'Location': 'Denver'},
 {'Speciality': 'Chemistry', 'Name': 'Jim', 'Location': 'Dallas'}]
```

**Code to delete key:value from dict**

```
import csv

data= []
for line in csv.DictReader(open('data.csv')):
    data.append(line)

for i in data:
    del i['Speciality']

print data
```

**Desired Data Format without using `del i['Speciality']`**

```
[{'Name': 'Matt', 'Location': 'Miami'}, 
 {'Name': 'Ben', 'Location': 'Las Vegas'}, 
 {'Name': 'Sarah', 'Location': 'Washington DC'}, 
 {'Name': 'Tom', 'Location': 'Denver'}, 
 {'Name': 'Jim', 'Location': 'Dallas'}]
```

Comment: Yes my code works, but it deletes the unwanted dictionary, and I don't want to delete any data.  Instead I was looking for an option to extract the data I do want into a new dict, leaving the old dict untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give a positive list of keys to copy over into the new dictionaries:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file))

keys = ['Name', 'Location']
new_data = [dict((k, d[k]) for k in keys) for d in data]

print new_data
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose we have,

```
l1 = [{'Location': 'Miami', 'Name': 'Matt', 'Speciality': 'Math'},
      {'Location': 'Las Vegas', 'Name': 'Ben', 'Speciality': 'Science'},
      {'Location': 'Washington DC', 'Name': 'Sarah', 'Speciality': 'Language Arts'},
      {'Location': 'Denver', 'Name': 'Tom', 'Speciality': 'Spanish'},
      {'Location': 'Dallas', 'Name': 'Jim', 'Speciality': 'Chemistry'}]
```

to create a new list of dictionaries that do not contain the keys 'Speciality' we can do,

```
l2 = []
for oldd in l1:
    newd = {}
    for k,v in oldd.items():
        if k != 'Speciality':
            newd[k] = v
    l2.append(newd)
```

and now l2 will be your desired output. In general you can exclude an arbitrary list of keys like so

```
exclude_keys = ['Speciality', 'Name']
l2 = []
    for oldd in l1:
        newd = {}
        for k,v in oldd.items():
            if k not in exclude_keys:
                newd[k] = v
        l2.append(newd)
```

the same can be done with an `include_keys` variable

```
include_keys = ['Name', 'Location']
l2 = []
    for oldd in l1:
        newd = {}
        for k,v in oldd.items():
            if k in include_keys:
                newd[k] = v
        l2.append(newd)
```

Comment: my actual data is more complex than this simple example.  Instead of creating a new list of dicts that DO NOT contain 'Speciality', how can I instead create a new list of dicts that DO contain 'Name' and 'Location'?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list of dicts limited to the keys you want with one line of code (Python 2.6+):

```
NLoD=[{k:d[k] for k in ('Name', 'Location')} for d in LoD]
```

Try it:

```
>>> LoD=[{'Speciality': 'Math', 'Name': 'Matt', 'Location': 'Miami'},
 {'Speciality': 'Science', 'Name': 'Ben', 'Location': 'Las Vegas'}, 
 {'Speciality': 'Language Arts', 'Name': 'Sarah', 'Location': 'Washington DC'},
 {'Speciality': 'Spanish', 'Name': 'Tom', 'Location': 'Denver'},
 {'Speciality': 'Chemistry', 'Name': 'Jim', 'Location': 'Dallas'}]
>>> [{k:d[k] for k in ('Name', 'Location')} for d in LoD]
[{'Name': 'Matt', 'Location': 'Miami'}, {'Name': 'Ben', 'Location': 'Las Vegas'}, {'Name': 'Sarah', 'Location': 'Washington DC'}, {'Name': 'Tom', 'Location': 'Denver'}, {'Name': 'Jim', 'Location': 'Dallas'}]
```

Since you are using csv, you can limit the columns that you read in the first place to the desired columns so you do not need to delete the undesired data:

```
dc=('Name', 'Location')        
with open(fn) as f:
    reader=csv.DictReader(f)
    LoD=[{k:row[k] for k in dc} for row in reader]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
keys_lst = ['Name', 'Location']

new_data={key:val for key,val in event.items() if key in keys_lst}
print(new_data)
```

Comment: That's just for one item in the list at a time, and there's a typo. I'm not sure what you're trying to add to the accepted answer, except maybe using `items()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30535686)

Comment: @domi27: It _does_ provide an answer. It appears to be a _wrong_ answer, but it's still an answer. If so, it has correctly been downvoted.